# Eclipse and tomcat but run web application from 'target' directory (created by maven)

Tags: java, tomcat

I am using Eclipse and tomcat but I want to configure the tomcat configuration to run from a directory in my 'target' directory.  The target directory is created by maven.

I have the project configured for maven.  The Java source is in src/main/java.

All of my jars/libs get deployed properly to:

{mywebapp}/target/web/webappSPR11-SNAPSHOT

I want tomcat to run my webapp from there.

This is tomcat7 and Juno.

I tried to change the server.xml to this:

```
<Context docBase="mywebapp/target/webappSPR11-SNAPSHOT" path="/mywebapp" reloadable="true" source="org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:mywebapp"/>
```

And I got:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Document base
```

How can I make this happen?

Comment: Looks like the docBase path is invalid

Comment: What OS are you using? How do you integrate Tomcat? (Probably not `mvn tomcat:run`.)

Comment: Mac.  I download the tomcat archive from the tomcat site.  Eclipse Juno already had a server configuration for tomcat, I setup a new tomcat server and then pointed the tomcat home setting to the path where I downloaded tomcat.  I think the issue, how does Eclipse/Tomcat know where I want to serve my webapp files from?

Comment: It looks like I need to change my deployment assembly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you have already installed eclipse m2e WTP support plugin.
This plugins allows to configure your maven webapp projects to run with "Run on Server" option.
In all cases, you will have to check whether your deployment assembly is collecting the 
right artifacts or not.
With maven, we may need some of dependencies to be available while running the web 
application. So, you need to include such dependencies as a part of your 
deployment assembly. In deployment assembly section, make sure you add the maven dependencies also.

And yes, with maven you don't have to worry about your .war file as m2e will add
the contents of src/main/webapp , src/main/resouces, src/main/classes to the deployment assembly directely.